# What does the .(Cat) on line 21 mean?

Tags: go, interface

This is code from [Golang Tutorial : Go Full Course at 2:37:32](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YzLrWHZa-Kc&t=9452s)

I cannot understand what he mean when using .(Cat) on kitty

Is he kind of type casting or something on the kitty interface to Cat type?(IDK what I am talking, please help)

Please share a link to the documentation if possible

```
var kitty2 Cat = kitty.(Cat)
```

```
package main

type Cat string

type Animal interface {
    happy() string
    sad() string
}

func (c Cat) happy() string {
    return "haha"
}

func (c Cat) sad() string {
    return ":("
}

func main() {
    var kitty Animal
    kitty = Cat("kitty")
    var kitty2 Cat = kitty.(Cat)
}
```

Comment: It's a "type assertion". Please take the Tour of Go for such language fundamentals.

Answer (score -1):

It is an attempt to type cast. Take a look at this lesson in the [tour](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15)
If they had done the following then you can use to variable `ok` to check if the type casting worked, here `ok` is of type `bool`

```golang
kitty, ok := kitty.(Cat)
```

Comment: There are no type cast in Go and you cannot attempt one.

Comment: @Volker so what is happening there?

Comment: A type assertion.

Comment: @Volker okay. So what does the variable `kitty` on the left hand side have?

Comment: It depends solely on the value of kitty on the right hand side. Note that your code redeclares kitty which is a bad practice. It's a matter of fact that there _are_ no casts in Go and neither a type conversion nor a type assertion are "casts" (which has a defined meaning for languages with C heritage).

Comment: @Volker in this example above the variable `kitty` is assigned to the value of type `Cat`. I do understand the Go in none of its documentation uses the the phrase type casting, but the principle is here.

Comment: "the variable kitty is assigned to the value of type Cat" is a false statement as it doesn't describe what happens. This might be a simple language problem. I prefer the language used in the language spec, the Tour of Go, and the official documentation. Please note that the principle of a type cast is _not_ present in Go, it was a deliberate design choice _not_ to allow type cast. And IMHO it is _not_ _helpful_ to talk about "type casts". Type conversions and type assertions are different and calling both a "type cast" blurs their difference.